# Prever um resultado através da probabilidade

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber se tem como, a partir de uma sequencia de 10 números eu prever os supostos próximos 10 números. Estes 10 números estão em um intervalo de 0 a 100.

**Explicando melhor a situação:**

Todos os dias vão ser gerados randomicamente 10 números. Eu gostaria de pegar os últimos 3 dias (ou mais se necessário) e "prever" os supostos próximos 10 números de amanhã por exemplo.

Há alguma maneira?

Comment: Eventualmente pode mas depende de uma série de fatores. Se eles são aleatórios, não tem como. Bom, até pode ter dependendo de como está implementado. Mas é algo extramente complexo, duvido que dê uma resposta aqui que realmente responda isto por completo. Mas pode estar enganado. Computação no significado mais profundo da palavra não é meu forte, sou mais um engenheiro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sendo a geração aleatória e independente das anteriores, não há forma de prever a próxima sequência.

O que podemos é determinar qual a probabilidade de a próxima sequência ser igual a uma já saída.

O número de combinações possíveis de 10 números retirados de um conjunto de 100 pode ser calculado pela seguinte [formula:](http://www.mathwords.com/c/combination_formula.htm)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado obtido para este caso é: `17310309456440`.

A probabilidade de sair uma determinada sequência é: `1/17310309456440`.

A probabilidade de sair um sequência igual a uma que já tenha saído é: `n/17310309456440`.
Sendo `n` o numero de sequências diferentes já saídas.

Após 3 dias a probabilidade de sair uma sequência igual é de `3/17310309456440` o que continua a ser muito reduzida: `1/5770103152146`.

Com o aumento do número de sequências saídas a probabilidade de sair uma repetida aumenta, mas este fato(haver sequências saídas) não influencia a próxima saída.
A probabilidade de sair um determinada sequência continua a ser `1/17310309456440`.